# Cognitive comparison of Milo Stanfield vs. the Observers in Fringe

Tags: fringe

In *Fringe* Season 3 episode 3, Milo Stanfield was the subject of a drug trial which aimed at improving his intelligence. Before identifying their suspect as Milo Stanfield in the beginning though, when the Fringe team (in the Alternate Universe) is still suspicious of the coincidences of chains of events leading to peoples' deaths, Agent Farnsworth mentions that it would be impossible for someone to willfully know how to set off such a chain of events since that would require solving an equation of *127*<sup>1</sup> variables. At the end of the episode, Milo is left having to interface with a computer since his thoughts got too complex for humans to interpret.

The Observers' tech gives the Observers a similar ability (with the addition of teleportation, and manipulating the morphology of the brain for controlled evolution), but let's focus solely on the tech's enabling of the ability to "predict futures". Remember, back in Season 3 episode 3, the reason that Milo's failed prediction that led to his capture failed in the first place was that he did not know to factor in the behaviour of Olivia from the *prime* universe, so his ability to predict the future is notably limited by facts/observations. Similarly, in a later season, after Peter implants the Observer's tech in his brain, we realize that when Olivia discovers Peter's plan to attack an Observer precinct he mentions how when he had been following Captain Windmark's lieutenants long enough to be able to predict their futures. So the tech's ability to predict futures is also limited by observations.

If someone born in the same era/time/generation as Milo Stanfield (specifically, with the exact same set of observations to work from) introduced the Observer's tech to their brain stem, who would have the more powerful cognitive ability? Could it be possible to simulate the portion of the Observers' tech for predicting futures with arbitrary doses of the same drug Milo had to take during his drug trial? If so, why didn't the people of the resistance give themselves the ability to predict futures by dosing themselves with the drug?

An obvious answer to the question of who would have the more powerful cognitive ability to predict futures (given the above situation) is to say that if the two people were basing their predictions off the same set of facts/observations then they would have a cognitive stalemate. Then could you give a reason for your assumption of why you think they would interpret the same observation in the exact same way and add the same fact(s) to their *knowledge base*?

---

<sup>1</sup> She throws out a number of variables at that point, and to the best of my memory I could swear it was 127, but that is not too relevant

Comment: Since the Observers have a culture, language, education and personal experience all built on their cognitive and pre-cognitive abilities I imagine they'd have the advantage.

Comment: This is one of the reasons I've added that Milo's competitor would have to be born from the same era (so that person with the Observer tech would not have that knowledge that the Observers would tend to have). The purpose is to put them on equal levels and see who would have a stronger ability at predicting futures.

Comment: Wasn't Milo OCD type personality? There are theories that brains of people with OCD work a bit differently than normal brain, and capable of much, much more as well. But it has as severe limitations - people with OCD are very difficult to communicate with simply because of that abnormality (that is: "elevated" brain function level). So it's a coin toss who would be more powerful in this specific case. Case in point: Milo's prediction wasn't failed - it was incomplete dataset that led to an error in logic chain. Prediction was perfect. Data it was based upon was not. Classic GIGO.

Comment: He didn't seem to show many symptoms of having OCD though, so I don't think this applies. His intelligence made him anti-social but I didn't see enough evidence of him being OCD; in fact, if you think of when his sister was trying to talk him out of killing people, he was way too confident to  be prone to any kind of anxiety in general. A person with some kind of anxiety disorder would not be that confident.